# PHP - String with ASCII-Extended chars only

Tags: php, regex

With PHP I would like to know whether my $string contains any non ASCII-Extended characters from 33 to 255 of this list: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Also, is it possible to include other assorted ASCII characters for rejection? Like 182 and 135 (¶ and ‡ symbols accordingly). I mean, if the $string has this ones, I would like to get a bool false too.

I know how to do this with ASCII, but not with ASCII-Extended.

Comment: How is ASCII `48` means `0` a **non ASCII-Extended character**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** please see this [working demo](https://ideone.com/KCXvpU).

**From ! to ÿ**

To check if you have any character that is **not** in the ASCII range 33 to 255 is very easy. Just use this regex:

```
`[^!-ÿ]`
```

This is a negated character class that matches any character **not** between `!` and `ÿ`. Do note that the extended ASCII range depends on the machine's locale. It should work for you.

**Also excluding `¶` and `‡`**

To also exclude these characters, we could break up our initial negated class into three ranges to make space around the two new character: from `!` to the character before `ˆ`... From the character after `ˆ` to the character before `¶`... From the character after `¶` to `ÿ`.

But it is much cleaner (and more maintainable) to add the two characters to a class of their own and join them with an **OR**. You can use this regex:

```
`[ˆ¶]|[^!-ÿ]`
```

- We have a match if either of the two characters in `[ˆ¶]` is found, OR `|`
- if the character is not in the `!-ÿ` range.

To add exclusions, just keep adding characters to the first class.

Comment: All these returns the same:

$string = 'asд€!$da:‰sdFf3Ff3 ';
$string = 'abc';
$string = 'д€';
echo preg_match('/[^!-ÿ]/','', $string);

Comment: @JackM. Your second parameter is empty, it should be the string. You have it in reverse. :) See working [demo](https://ideone.com/KCXvpU)

Comment: yeah sorry am confused because am trying to convert this to ereg replace so I can get rid of all non Extended ASCII characters

Comment: WARNING: once you allow byte values above 126, you've entered into the world of character encoding, so you first need to fix your inputs. By allowing byte values 33-255 (!-ÿ), you are allowing all of UTF-8, at which point you aren't actually doing anything useful in terms of limiting the allowable characters. *Byte 0xFF (255) is only ÿ in ISO-8859-1/etc.* This smiley: ☺ is just the three bytes "â˜º" (0xE2 0x98 0xBA) but the website tells your browser that it should display them as a single character using UTF-8 instead of as 3 characters in ISO-8859-1. Read my answer for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Extended ASCII is decimal 128-255, and normal (7-bit) ASCII printable characters are 32 (space) to 126 (tilde).

So, a regular expression to find any 8-bit characters outside of the normal printable range would be:

```
/[^ -~]/
```

Basically, that says "NOT space through tilde".  In PHP:

```
$nonprintable_or_extended = preg_match('/[^ -~]/', $string) === 1;
```

Edited to add:
I re-read your question, and on second thought I think you also want to allow for *some* "Extended ASCII" characters. There's no simple answer for that, because anything above code point 127 involves *character encoding*. In the US, we typically use one of these 3:

1. ISO-8859-1 defines Latin-1 and allows for e-grave, e-acute, etc.
   characters in the range 128-255, with some gaps
   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso_8859-1).
2. cp1252 (or Windows
   Codepage 1252) is basically ISO-8859-1 except it adds more
   characters in the range 129-159, which ISO-8859-1 left unassigned
   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1252).
3. UTF-(8, 16, 32) strings use sets of
   higher-order ASCII characters to address code points in the whole
   Unicode spectrum (65535 and beyond), so figuring out "what is a
   valid printable character here?" will require more thought.

Edited per the comments below: if you want to allow certain characters, first standardize on the input encoding. We'll operate in UTF-8, and we can check and convert the encoding for cp1252/ISO-8859-1:

```
// Validate the UTF-8 (from drupal_validate_utf8()).
// @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_validate_utf8/7
if (strlen($string) != 0 && preg_match('/^./us', $string) !== 1) {
  // Convert to UTF-8 if it isn't already (assuming input was "Western" cp1252/ISO).
  $string = @iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $string);
}
```

Now `$string` is guaranteed to be a valid UTF-8-encoded string. Then, to allow only single-byte "extended ASCII" (the Latin-1 and supplements offered by cp1252), and transliterate similar-ish characters in a locale-aware way:

```
// Ensure the locale is right for our iconv() operations.
// This establishes how transliteration will determine the appropriate destination character(s).
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');
$string = iconv('utf-8', 'CP1252//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
```

At this point `$string` will be a cp1252, single-byte-representation string; anything outside of that range will be transliterated (if possible) or discarded. Here you can apply further filtering using REGEX, such as:

```
// Allow only printable characters (exclude control codes below \x20 [space char]),
// and only the Euro cp1252 character (\x80) and A-tilde (Ãã) characters (\xC3 and \xE3).
$filtered_string = preg_replace('[\x20-\x7F\x80\xC3\xE3]+', '', $string);
```

Comment: I just made a test.php with:
<?php
$string = '例子';
$nonprintable_or_extended = preg_match('/[^ -~]/', $string) === 1;
echo $nonprintable_or_extended ? 'FAIL' : 'PASS';
?>
And it worked, when I stored the file as UTF-8 (without BOM), because of how UTF-8 works. Anything else will get into Unicode encoding problems, since those Chinese characters require a multi-byte encoding.

Comment: Try with the € symbol (its an ASCII extended character though) I am still gathering information regarding those two char encodings you advised. btw, thanks for helping.

Comment: If you want to allow for some cherry-picked ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1) or cp1252 characters, you will have to add them to the REGEX:

$nonprintable_or_extended = preg_match('/[^ -~€]/', $string) === 1;

Comment: Simple answer that works ;) Thanks ASCII + € + ... whatever I need will be added. ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that's very brittle without knowing the encoding of the string. The REGEX might be better written /[^ -~\x80]/, using the escape sequence to represent the Euro symbol as it is in cp1252. That's only valid in cp1252.  If the Euro symbol came in as UTF-8 it'd be the bytes 0xE2 0x82 0xAC, or in UTF-16 it could be 0x20 0xAC or 0xAC 0x20 (depending on endianness), etc.

Comment: So far I am doing this: preg_match('/^([\x00-\x7F€])*$/', $string)

Comment: Jay, what about removing all non ASCII characters from a string with exception for the € symbol and ã letter ? (Am looking for the ereg_replace regex)

Comment: The answer depends entirely on the input encoding. So, I'll assume that it's coming in as ISO-8859-1/cp1252 (what modern browsers collectively call "Western"), and we can use the single codes \x80 (Euro), \xC3 (upper-case Ã), and \xE3 (lower-case ã). I'll also write it with preg_replace() since ereg_replace() is deprecated. $filtered_string = preg_replace('[\x00-\x7F\x80\xC3\xE3]+', '', $string)

Comment: Edited my answer to better expand on some of these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting extended ASCII character set use:

```
$extended = preg_match('/[\x7f-\xff]/', $str );
```

Comment: It is working fine. It returns `true` for Chinese characters but returns false for regular ASCII characters.

Comment: Yes, but € symbol or even an 'ã' is not passing :(

Comment: Are you sure you are using it right? `€` is returning `true` and without `€` (just ASCII) returns `false`?

Comment: Yep, your code works fine for ASCII but I need Extended-ASCII ;)

Comment: `[\x7f-\xff]` is the range for extended ASCII only

Comment: I dunno why and even the var $extended ... >>var<< is not working: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)

Comment: `var` shouldn't be there, that was my mistake (fixed)